# Should hackathon-starter project implement babel compiler?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm going to start a project based on [hackathon-starter](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter). I noticed all code is written in ES6 but there's no babel compiler. Should I implement it? If yes, what steps for it?

Comment: The only ES6 code in there is code that runs on Node 6 fine without Babel. If you use ES6 in the client side, it's entirely depend on how strongly you want to use ES6 there, and what browsers you care about for your hackathon project. You could for instance just say your app is chrome-only and not worry about it.

Comment: Thanks!! Helped me!